# Combining multiple data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, tidyverse

I am computing `statistics` (i.e., mean, max, median etc) for `winter season` comprised of Months 11 & 12 of `previous year` and Months 1-4 of `following year`.

```
mydate <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), to= as.Date("2019-12-31"), by="day"))
colnames(mydate) <- "Date"
DF <- data.frame(A = runif(3652,0,10), 
                   J = runif(3652,0,8), 
                   X = runif(3652,0,12), 
                   Z = runif(3652,0,10), 
                  mydate)

mydata <- DF %>% mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Date,Year,Month), names_to = "variable", values_to = "values") %>% 
  filter(Month == 11 | Month == 12 | Month == 01 | Month == 02 | Month == 03 | Month == 04) %>% 
  mutate(W_Year = ifelse(Month > 10, Year+1, Year)) %>% 
  filter(W_Year != 2019) %>% 
  group_by(W_Year, variable) %>% 
  mutate(Cumulative = cumsum(values)) %>%
  mutate(NewDate = ymd(paste("2020", Month, day(Date), sep = "-"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(variable, NewDate) %>%
  summarise(Median = median(Cumulative))
```

I would then need to `combine` `mydata` with the `data.frame` of `accumulated` values for the most recent year, which in my case is the `year 2019` as an additional column.

```
X = c("A", "J","X", "Z")

Data2019 <- DF %>% mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Date,Year,Month), names_to = "variable", values_to = "values") %>% 
  filter(between(Month,5,10)) %>% 
  filter(Year == 2019) %>% 
  group_by(Year, variable) %>% 
  mutate(Precipitation = cumsum(values)) %>%
  mutate(NewDate = ymd(paste("2020", Month,day(Date), sep = "-"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(variable, NewDate) %>%
  select(c(4,6,7)) %>% 
  slice(match(X, variable))
```

While `combining` the two `data.frame`, i am getting `mis-match` error for number of rows- which i believe is due to `leap year` but do not know how to overcome this problem. Any way forward would help. Thank you,

```
Data_plot <- data.frame(mydata, Data2019[,2])
```

Comment: Do you really need a `data.frame` with 7305 rows to demonstrate the problem you're having? You'd make your question & code a lot more manageable if you can provide a more *minimal* example (plus code). For example, can you reduce the many `tidyverse` operations to the few that are essential and relevant to your problem?

Comment: not really, thanks. I am learning :). I trim out some of the `tidyverse` operation and reduce my `data.frame` `size`.